# Watson assistant what entity should I use to capture a complaint/request text with no format(any text)?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I have a use case to capture Complaint/Request from user. How can i define an entity for handling these slots(subject of request, description of request). Here I cant use regex because these two slots can be any text, How can i define and capture the request.

Comment: handle them in what sense?

Comment: Prompt for subject slot and then prompt for description slot.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48721487/watson-conversation-dialogue-how-to-save-user-input-using-slot). But without an entity with regex format how can i capture response using a slot. Isn't that completely possible? Is there any workaround? How can i use manage handler to cancel that dialogue if there is a work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to capture a complaint or request, you need to design if it is allowed anytime or only after prompting the user.

If you know that the input is a complaint or request, I would recommend [taking the full input](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/expression-language.html#expressions-for-accessing-objects) and store or handle it as complaint text. Watson Assistant allows access to the entire input text. It also provides location information for detected entities. If you define certain keywords, e.g. for specific complaint categories, the entity would be detected and could serve for tagging the complaint or filing it along with categories.

Comment: i have designed in a way to prompt(after understanding his intent to raise a complaint) what type of complaint he have and wait for user input for type, based on the type i will acknowledge the type. Now to capture the Subject and description am using slots. As you mentioned if am trying to capture user input using <? input.text ?> i am getting spEL error in dialogue node, I am trying capture input text against each slot.  `"context":{
    "subject":"<? input.text ?>"
  }` . Capturing input text against input text is what i do not understand. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Why not create Entity as Complaint/Request and through a Skill pass the response from NodeMailer as an Email. It could we done through Skill's code. So user input be like My Complaint is (*)  or Request is (*).

And through Slots we can ask user for his Email address having 1 more entity as "Email" from where WA team can connect him.

Comment: I have no idea about a Skill/Node mailer in Watson assistant here. And why would we expect user to enter My request is () and My complaint is (). The case is he comes for raising a complaint and after we ask about complaint type(which is an entity), then we should ask for subject of complaint and description. At least ask for description which dont have any regex pattern.