# Save user input (string) in Watson assistant

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I'm building a chat-bot application based on IBM Watson. I need to save the user input into a variable.

I searched the web and I only found tutorials where the input must be of entity sys-(number, day, time, location, person).

In my dialog I ask the user about his identifier. This identifier should be an alphanumerical string.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 3):

User input can be accessed as a String by this expression: `<?input.text?>`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [IBM Cloud solution tutorial that creates a chatbot](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials/slack-chatbot-database-watson.html#build-a-database-driven-slackbot). It uses identifiers for emails, URIs and conferences.

I see two options for your case:

1. Define an entity type "identifier" and use a pattern in its definition. The pattern would be the alphanumerical regular expression. For a slot, assign the entity of "identifier" as necessary input.
2. Use the value of the [input variable](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-expression-language#expression-language-builtin-vars). Thereafter, extract the identifier by [applying string methods](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-strings).

To access the actual value in a detected entity, use the `value` property. See the [Watson Assistant docs on entity properties](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-expression-language#expression-language-entity-props) for the full syntax and examples.

Comment: OK. I created an entity with value "identifier" and pattern "^Id[A-Za-z0-9]+$". If the input is IdAB123, I get "identifier" as the result instead of the real input. How to solve this?

Comment: see the last paragraph of my answer which I added

Comment: I use a slot and I tried @identifier.value already in CHECK FOR. And $myVariable in SAVE IT AS. I still get "identifier" saved to $myVariable . I build my dialog using wizard.